# Sass or CSS with PHP what to choose

Tags: php, css, sass

I read the sass documentation and I find it a good idea of a language, but, I used to do the same thing with simple php and css. This is what I mean:

File name: style.css.php

```
<?php
$color = 'red';
$width = '234px';
?>

.button{
    background: <?= $color ?>;
    width: <?= $width ?>;
}

.another_class{
    color: <?= $color ?>;
}
```

Now, SASS has to be installed and learned and so forth, and I can't find a good reason not to use the method above.

Why should I use SASS instead of using PHP inside CSS? Is there any plus-point for me to learn it? Is there any problem in using the above method?

Comment: how would you deal nested level of selectors in php? Or mixins, or abstract classes, or...?

Comment: there is a lot more to Sass or LESS than just variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS is not only variables definition SASS is much more, you can use nesting, mixins, functions, selectors inheritance... for example, try to do this simply with CSS and PHP:

```
$color = '#852D4A';

a {
    color: $color;
}

a:hover {
    color: darken($color, 10);
}
```

More info about SASS darken function: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method

Comment: That's what I came here to write

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP the file will be processed for each request, while if you use SASS the CSS is generated already (including minified CSS).

Also, unless you write your own parser engine, your "features" will be limited.

If you don't like the syntax of SASS, perhaps you'll like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) more.